# Find cliques in an un directed graph using Pregel/Spark in scala

Tags: scala, graph, apache-spark, clique, clique-problem

I want to utilize Pregel/ spark-pregel implementation to find the cliques of an un-directed graph using Scala. 
Any suggestions or algorithms to do that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Pregel is suited to finding cliques.

Comment: did you get any result @mas? I'd like to find cliques on graphx graphs too